# 'UMReactNativeAdapter/UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h' file not found

Tags: react-native, expo

After upgrading react native from 0.59.1 to 0.61.5, I got this error.

Before upgrading, I used expo and ejected from expo.

Does this error has something to do with expo?

If it is, How can I solve this?

I'm not using expo anymore.

So if it's a way to remove expo from my react native project perfectly,

please help me solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It happens because you need to install and configure [unimodules](https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/).

Run this command:

```
npm install react-native-unimodules
```

Then add this line to the top of your Podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods'
```

And this line inside the target inside your Podfile:

```
use_unimodules!
```

Then finally do `pod install` and build project.

Comment: react-native-unimodules replaced by expo-modules